# image not displaying in webpage, but link to image works

Tags: html, image

Im building a webpage and have the following code in the page:

`<a href="#"><img alt="chat" href="images/chat.jpg">Chat now</a>`

The image "chat.jpg" is in the images folder, which is in the same folder as index.html, and if i browse to "localhost/site/images/chat.jpg" it displays but it doesnt show up in the index page at "localhost/site/index.html".
I have tried changing the href to "/site/images/chat.jpg" and the same thing happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `href` attribute for `img` elements. You are looking for [the `src` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-img-src).

[Validators](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) are useful tools.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for your problem.

```
<a href="#"><img alt="chat" src="images/chat.jpg">Chat now</a>
```

Comment: that's what the other answer said

Comment: yes but this is the piece of code he was looking for to get it to work.

Comment: The other answer explains what is not working, you just put the code there and said nothing else. A good answer should  include an explanation of the solution.